# Custom Routes with kentico Portal Template

Tags: asp.net, kentico

Asp.net allows us to register new custom routes

http://www.example.com/products.aspx?category=software

to call them like that : http://www.example.com/products/software

```
 void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

    }
 static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapPageRoute("testroute", "Test/{parame}", "~/Default.aspx");
    }
```

This method works in Kentico but only for  .aspx pages (for example for pages in ~/CMSPages/Default.aspx).
My question is how to achive same results for pages created with Portal Template approach?
I was trying to make my own HttpHandler

```
public class CustomHandlerProduct : IHttpHandler
{
    public CustomHandlerProduct()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        // To enable pooling, return true here.
        // This keeps the handler in memory.
        get { return false; }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
    }
}
```

or even HttpModule according to this article
[link to CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/335968/Implementing-HTTPHandler-and-HTTPModule-in-ASP-NET)

but i can not achive desired results

any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use Portal engine, is there a reason not to use Kentico URL rewriting capabilities? Wildcard URLs work very similarly to routes. See the documentation https://docs.kentico.com/display/K82/Wildcard+URLs

Comment: I was trying to use Wildcard URLs but this solution doesn't work for me . Do u have any other suggestions?

Comment: Does it work with .aspx extension? If yes, it might be just extension-less configuration, see https://docs.kentico.com/display/K82/Extensionless+and+custom+URLs . Did you removed your custom routes when you tried the wildcard?

Comment: yah, the problem was in my custom routes. TY mivra